# Control.Monad.Writer not working in haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I have been trying to compile Haskell code all day – again – involving Control.Monad.Writer. Here is a code example that won't compile from [*Learn You a Haskell*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more):

```
import Control.Monad.Writer  

gcd' :: Int -> Int -> Writer [String] Int  
gcd' a b  
    | b == 0 = do  
        tell ["Finished with " ++ show a]  
        return a  
    | otherwise = do  
        tell [show a ++ " mod " ++ show b ++ " = " ++ show (a `mod` b)]  
        gcd' b (a `mod` b)
```

I receive this error:

```
No instance for (Show (Writer [String] Int))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Show (Writer [String] Int))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I have tried compiling code my teacher wrote today also involving Control.Monad.Writer but nothing works.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, gedit, and GHC 7.4.1.

All the Writer monad programs from *Learn You a Haskell* have failed to compile, and I am pretty stuck as it is.

Comment: You aren't using `print` anywhere in the code you've posted. I'm guessing you're doing something like `print (gcd' 8 4)` somewhere?

Comment: Nope, no print. I call from terminal gcd' 42 422 and get that error msg. I tried examples from my teacher today but nothing has compiled and i always get the same kind of error messages - (like the one posted above). I really want to learn Haskell, but the road is getting kind of bumpy:)

Comment: Try `runWriter (gcd' 42 422)`.

Comment: If you want code blocks, the best approach is not to use `<code>...</code>`, but to prepend four spaces to every line (which can be done by selecting the text and clicking the "{}" button).  I fixed this up for you, along with a couple other formatting changes (for instance, it's better [not to include a "hello" or a signature](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)).

Comment: I feel embarrassed and ashamed now, but thank you Vitus, that was my problem.

Comment: Oh, no, do not feel embarrassed. We learn by doing mistakes; we've all been there, too!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You apparently entered something like

```
ghci> gcd' 12345 6789
```

at the ghci prompt. Thus you asked ghci to print a value of type `Writer [String] Int`, but there's no `Show` instance for `Writer` types, hence ghci can't print it. You need to apply `runWriter` or a similar function,

```
ghci> runWriter $ gcd' 12345 6789
```

should work.

Comment: Yes that was my problem, Thank you.

Comment: Echoing what Vitus said, don't feel embarrassed. That's a rather common mistake. The frequency decreases with experience, but doesn't reach 0 for a loong time.