# Unable to compile Writer Monad example from "Learn you a Haskell"

Tags: haskell, monads

The following code, which is [verbatim from LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more), doesn't compile.  Code and compile-time error are included below.  On the LYAH page, the code is ~15% down the page, yay emacs browser :)

Any ideas why?  Am I overlooking something totally obvious?

(Despite the similarity in post-titles, I think my question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216637/control-monad-writer-not-working-in-haskell).)

---

Here's the code (in a file which I named `testcopy.hs`)

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

logNumber :: Int -> Writer [String] Int
logNumber x = Writer (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x])

multWithLog :: Writer [String] Int
multWithLog = do
    a <- logNumber 3
    b <- logNumber 5
    return (a*b)
```

And here's the compile-time error:

```
Prelude> :l testcopy.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( testcopy.hs, interpreted )
testcopy.hs:4:15:
    Not in scope: data constructor `Writer'
    Perhaps you meant `WriterT' (imported from Control.Monad.Writer)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

LYAH is outdated in this example. You should use the `writer` smart constructor method instead of the (now non-existent) `Writer` data constructor.

To expand a bit, these data types were updated to be more compatible with monad transformers. As a result, there is a general `WriterT`, for use in a monad transformer stack, and a `Writer` type synonym that composes `WriterT` with `Identity`. Because of this, there is no longer a data constructor associated specifically with the `Writer` type (since `Writer` is a type synonym).

Luckily, despite this complication, the solution is pretty simple: replace `Writer` with `writer`.

Comment: I guess it was optimistic of me to think that replacing `Writer` with `writer` would get it to run :)   Doing so results in the following error for the `multWithLog` function (and a similar error for the `logNumber` function): `No instance for (Monad (writer [String])) arising from a do statement`.  I'll keep playing around with it.

Comment: @DipakC Leave the type signature the same. Replace the function call `Writer` with a call to `writer`. A lowercase starting letter in a type signature always refers to a type variable, which is not what we want here. We want the concrete type `Writer`.

Comment: I mean, who wouldn't want a concrete typewriter?

Comment: @justinhj In regards to your edit, both `Control.Monad.Writer` and `Control.Monad.Trans.Writer` export `Writer` (and the main associated things), so it should not be necessary to change the import.

Comment: Apologies in that case. Does it require a particular package? When I import Control.Monad.Writer I get "Could not find module" and I have the standard Haskell platform installed

Comment: @justinhj Hmm that's strange, Haskell platform should come with the necessary package. It's [mtl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) if you want to try installing it. [This](https://www.haskell.org/platform/contents.html) seems to indicate that Haskell platform should include it, but installing it is worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks I'll check that

Answer (score 2):

The correct version in GHC 7.10.3 should be like this

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

logNumber :: Int -> Writer [String] Int
logNumber x = writer (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x])

multWithLog :: Writer [String] Int
multWithLog = do
    a <- logNumber 3
    b <- logNumber 5
    return (a*b)
```