# Why Writer constructor causes syntax error

Tags: haskell

I am reading tut from http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#useful-monadic-functions

Copied listing to my file, but it doesn't compile.

```
import Control.Monad.Writer  

logNumber :: Int -> Writer [String] Int  
logNumber x = Writer (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x])  

multWithLog :: Writer [String] Int  
multWithLog = do  
    a <- logNumber 3  
    b <- logNumber 5  
    return (a*b)

Main.hs:4:15: error:                
    • Data constructor not in scope:                                    
        Writer :: (Int, [[Char]]) -> Writer [String] Int                
    • Perhaps you meant one of these:                                   
        ‘WriterT’ (imported from Control.Monad.Writer),                 
        variable ‘writer’ (imported from Control.Monad.Writer)          
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

How to resolve it? Everything seems to be correct.

Comment: Did you read the error? "Perhaps you meant one of these: ‘WriterT’ (imported from Control.Monad.Writer), variable ‘writer’ (imported from Control.Monad.Writer)"

Comment: I read, however, I want to use Writer, not WriterT. The above error left me wondering why book's code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

LYAH was written when `Control.Monad.Writer` still exported a `Writer` constructor. Now, you have to import `Control.Monad.Trans.Writer`, which defines the `WriterT` monad transformer as well as a simple `Writer` type defined as

```
type Writer w = WriterT w Identity
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't actually correct (or at least, not fully correct); I'll delete if you unaccept it. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/26415122/1126841 instead.

Comment: I can't really fix this answer, since I don't fully understand how the monad modules have change; for instance, I don't even *have* `Control.Monad.Writer` in my 8.0.2 installation any more.